# Set "MultiPatch" as feature class filter in arcpy scripts (ArcMap10)

Tags: arcmap, python-script-tool

As mentioned in ArcMap10.X documentation (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/programming-a-toolvalidator-class.htm), it is possible to set filters in tool parameters of python tool scripts.

So for example, for a parameter type "Feature Class" or "Feature Layer", the following geometry filters are selectable from a check list:

> A list of allowable feature class types, specified with the values
>   "Point", "Multipoint", "Polyline", "Polygon", "MultiPatch", "Sphere",
>   "Annotation", "Dimension". More than one value can be supplied to the
>   filter.

So, when selecting a layer or feature class, only the files with selected geometries are shown.

However, when I try to set filter, the option "MultiPatch" doesn't appear in the checklist (see image below):

[image: Configuration of filter in tool script]

According to documentation, "Multipatch" and "Sphere" options should appear in the checklist, but they don't. Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?. Another solution would be programming a ToolValidator class to set the "MultiPatch" option, using guidelines in the link above, but I don't know exactly how to proceed in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. I am not able to use the `Multipatch` and some others in 10.6 either. The workaround for this would be to use the `ToolValidator` class.

Tool properties > Validation tab > Edit button. The code is open in the editor you've set up in the Geoprocessing menu > Geoprocessing Options > Script Tool Editor.

You only need to add a single line (`self.params[0].filter.list = ["MULTIPATCH"]`):

```
def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    self.params[0].filter.list = ["MULTIPATCH"]
    return
```

Now users of your tool can only see the feature classes of `Multipatch` type when browsing for the input data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. That was just what I needed.

Comment: No worries, glad it worked!